# TargetReplicaSelector RandomSecondaryReplica endpoint not found

Tags: azure-service-fabric

No endpoint found for the service '{serviceB}' partition '{guid}' that matches the specified TargetReplicaSelector : 'RandomSecondaryReplica'

This is an error that has not always showed up, but it does sometimes.

I'm calling a stateful service B from another stateful service A, with service remoting, asking for a random secondary replica, to access state written to the primary.

I can see in Explorer that the partition is there and shows OK, and it has a primary and two ActiveSecondaries.

The service B has following:

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceReplicaListener> CreateServiceReplicaListeners()
{
    return new[] { new ServiceReplicaListener(context =>
        this.CreateServiceRemotingListener(context), listenOnSecondary: true) };
}
```

I get all the partitions by this:

```
return Enumerable.Range(0, PartitionConstants.Partitions).Select(x =>
                ServiceProxy.Create<IServiceB>(
                    ServiceBUri,
                    new ServicePartitionKey(x),
                    TargetReplicaSelector.RandomSecondaryReplica));
```

And the overall settings must be OK since sometimes it does work. And I know the primary is responding because I have saved state there.

So, what could cause this error when I can actually see the partition there, with the secondary replicas?

**Update1 :** Restarting the calling service made connection work. But they started together, and well after both had been running and working, the problem persisted, until I restarted. Howcome?

**Update2 :** This happens when whole cluster is started. At startup, Service A primaries calls Service B primaries for some registration. A polls B to know that it has initiated its internal state before doing this.

Then when this is complete, Service A goes on to check if its internal state needs update, and if so, it will call Service B again to retrieve state. Since it will not do any writing to B state, it calls secondary replicas. And here is when endpoint is not found.
When I restart Service A, endpoints are found.

*Could it be that primaries are working and OK, but the secondaries are not yet OK?
How can I ascertain this? **Is there some service fabric class that I can access to know whether the secondary will be found if I call for it?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a [service primer found here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-data-aggregation/blob/master/HealthMetrics.Common/ServicePrimer.cs), solved this issue. Seems like not all partition replicas was ready when being called.

Basically, what it does is counting all replicas of all partitions via FabricClient, until expected count is found.

Here is code:

```
public async Task WaitForStatefulService(Uri serviceInstanceUri, CancellationToken token)
        {
            StatefulServiceDescription description =
                await this.Client.ServiceManager.GetServiceDescriptionAsync(serviceInstanceUri) as StatefulServiceDescription;

            int targetTotalReplicas = description.TargetReplicaSetSize;
            if (description.PartitionSchemeDescription is UniformInt64RangePartitionSchemeDescription)
            {
                targetTotalReplicas *= ((UniformInt64RangePartitionSchemeDescription)description.PartitionSchemeDescription).PartitionCount;
            }

            ServicePartitionList partitions = await this.Client.QueryManager.GetPartitionListAsync(serviceInstanceUri);
            int replicaTotal = 0;

            while (replicaTotal < targetTotalReplicas && !token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await Task.Delay(this.interval);
                //ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(this, "CountyService waiting for National Service to come up.");

                replicaTotal = 0;
                foreach (Partition partition in partitions)
                {
                    ServiceReplicaList replicaList = await this.Client.QueryManager.GetReplicaListAsync(partition.PartitionInformation.Id);

                    replicaTotal += replicaList.Count(x => x.ReplicaStatus == System.Fabric.Query.ServiceReplicaStatus.Ready);
                }
            }
        }
```